# Get key in groovy maps

Tags: groovy, maps

```
def map = [name:"Gromit", likes:"cheese", id:1234]
```

I would like to access map in such a way that I can get the key

something like the output should be

map.keys returns array of string. basically i just want to get the keys

output:

```
name
likes
id
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

try [`map.keySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29)

and if you want an array:

```
map.keySet() as String[]; // thx @tim_yates
```

Or, more groovy-ish:

```
map.each{
    key, value -> print key;
}
```

**Warning:** In Jenkins, the groovy-ish example is subtly broken, as it depends on an iterator. Iterators aren't safe in Jenkins Pipeline code unless wrapped in a @NonCPS function.

Comment: or `map.keySet() as String[]`

Comment: or `map.keySet().collect()`

Comment: or `map.keySet() as List`.

Answer (score 10):

```
def map = [name:"Gromit", likes:"cheese", id:1234]
    
println map*.key
```

> In groovy * is use for iterate all