# Iterating over keys and values in a Map

Tags: java

Sometimes I find myself duplicating code to extract both key and value entries from a Map (when testing/debugging a third-party API, for example).

```
Map<String, String> someMap;
Set<String> keys = someMap.keySet();
for(int j=0;j<someMap.size();j++){
    String key = (String) keys.toArray()[j];
    System.out.println("key > " + key + "  : value = " + someMap.get(key));
}
```

I know Groovy has some great abstractions for this (e.g. [Get key in groovy maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898062/get-key-in-groovy-maps)), but I'm constrained to POJ. Surely there must be a more elegant and less verbose way to do this, in Java I mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify the code by using the for each loop:

```
Map<String, String> someMap;
for(String key : someMap.keySet()){
    System.out.println("key > " + key + "  : value = " + someMap.get(key));
}
```

Or you do this with the entry set. Amit provided some code for that while I was still editing my answer ;-)

Comment: This solution is indeed more elegant then the original, but note that for iterating both keys and values - usually it is unadvised to iterate over keys and then get the value using the `get()` method - due to the performance overhead of an extra look up. When you iterate over the `Entry` set, it is expected to perform faster.

Comment: After reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html, I must agree with Amit. But for implementation purposes, this is my preffered answer. Thanks guys

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Entry<String,String>` and iterate over it with a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). You get the `Entry` object by using [`Map.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29).

The key and value from an entry can be extracted using [`Entry.getKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey%28%29) and [`Entry.getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29)

Code example:

```
Map<String, String> someMap;
for (Entry<String,String> entry : someMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key > " + entry.getKey()+ "  : value = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to do, Google collections has a [Maps](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) API that provides some helper functions to transform maps etc.

If you're looking to just pretty print the map, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120408/222867) post may be useful